How can I resolve "Nonnull field 'messagingSenderId' is null" when logging into Firebase?
I'm working in Android Studio using Flutter to create an app, but I'm failing to connect to Firebase to signup or login.
I am getting the following exception:
E/flutter (10369): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Nonnull field "messagingSenderId" is null., ExecutionException, Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Nonnull field "messagingSenderId" is null., Stacktrace: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Nonnull field "messagingSenderId" is null.

I was trying to initialize Firebase so that I could signup or login as a user.
